# http request takes too much time only when it is actually deployed on server

Tags: node.js, request, http-post, axios, fetch

I'm trying to make POST request on front page via 'jquery ajax' to my server, and then with that data from front make POST request to outer server on my server. Using that final response I got from outer request, I wanna render new data into my front using ajax success function.
It seemed to be working well on local server, but when I deploy this project with heroku or azure, this whole process take 1000~2000ms and doesn't seem to be working at all.
what's wrong with my code?

I'm trying to build some detecting system that would notify users if there's a vacancy on wanted course. so I let user to pick a class and at the same time I call a function to check if there's a vacancy on that class via POST request to school server.

```
//index.html

//in front page, when user pick a course to start observing, I send POST to my server
function scanEmpty(data,cn,elem){
            $.ajax({
                url: './getLeftSeat',
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data+`&cn=${cn}`,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('got!')
                }
            })
        }
```

```
//app.js

// when I get POST from my server I call scanEmpty()
app.post('/getLeftSeat', async (req,res) => {
  scanEmpty(qs.stringify(req.body), req.body["cn"], () => {res.json({success: true})})
})

// and that is like this
const scanEmpty = async(data, CN, cb) => {
    if(await parseGetLeftSeat(await getData(data), CN)) cb()
    else {
        await scanEmpty(data,CN,cb)
    }
}

// send POST to school server and get response using axios
async function getData(data) {
    return await axios.post(school_server_url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'});
}

// it's just parsing and get data that I want
const parseGetLeftSeat = async (res, CN) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $("#premier1 > div > table > tbody > tr > td").each((i, e) => {
            if (e.firstChild && e.firstChild.data == CN && e.next) {
                const tmp = e.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.firstChild.data.split('/')
                resolve(Number(tmp[1].trim()) - Number(tmp[0].trim()) < 1 ? false : true)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

It works alright though takes 1000~2000 ms when actually on deploy server while it takes 100~200 ms on local server. I tested some codes and it looks like axios.post() is the one. but even if I change it to node-fetch, the result was the same. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: If you are using a free heroku server, your app is not going to run as fast as it will locally. Those servers are  shared and have limited bandwidth.

Comment: @cullanrocks I've thought about that, and tried azure free trial. but same result. :( Is auzre free trial same with free heroku?

Comment: I've never used Azure so I'm not sure. Generally, anything hosted will be slower than local, but hosting service often offer tiered service, shared vs dedicated servers etc.. I'm also a bit rusty on my jQuery, but if .each is based off a for loop than the whole algorithm is running at a pretty bad run time.